# Validate SQL Query Syntax with Python and SQLite

Tags: python, sqlite

I am using Python to execute a series of SQLite queries from a `.sql` file. It seems like there should be a good way to check the syntax of the queries to verify that they are all written correctly and will execute. This is especially important because these queries will for both MySQL and SQLite, so any MySQL-specific syntax should be caught and flagged.

Of course, I could just execute the queries and look for an exception. But it seems like there should be a better way than that.

Comment: If you can split up each statement, you can create prepared queries from them, but not actually execute them. Splitting them up might be tricky if you have semicolons in strings/comments, though there might be a SQLite function to do it (I can't remember).

Comment: I've used regexes to split the statements up into a list of strings. I'm having trouble finding how to keep the statements from executing. I could use `sqlite3.Connection.execute()` and then `sqlite3.Connection.rollback()`, but that seems inefficient.

Comment: Looks like Python's built-in bindings don't have the ability to create prepared statements. You might have to use a different binding or language.

Comment: Hi @Bryant, with Python am trying to read a .sql file and check for some rules and notify if not followed. Could you please let me know how you split up each sql statement from file into a list?

Comment: Oh man, it's been so long I don't recall what the regex was. A starting point might be to 1. iterate across lines, 2. remove `--.*` comments from each line, 3. rejoin list, 4. split across semi-colons, and 5. remove line endings. Good luck!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've settled with creating an in-memory database and executing the queries in which I am interested. However, the following code example is very slow and I will continue looking for a better solution. Also, I am aware of the vulnerability to SQL injection attacks in the following code, but that is not something with which I am concerned at the moment.

```
import sqlite3

# open the SQL file and read the contents
f_contents = open("example.sql").read()

# Use regexes to split the contents into individual SQL statements.
# This is unrelated to the issues I'm experiencing, show I opted not
# to show the details. The function below simply returns a list of
# SQL statements
stmnt_list = split_statements(f_contents)

temp_db = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")

good_stmnts = []    # a list for storing all statements that executed correctly
for stmnt in stmnt_list:
    # try executing the statement
    try:
        temp_db.execute(stmnt)
    except Exception as e:
        print("Bad statement. Ignoring.\n'%s'" % stmnt)
        continue
    good_stmnts.append(stmnt)

temp_db.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a sql parsing  module you should be able to attempt a parse of each statement without having to execute it and rollback. In theory this will be much more efficient.

---

*edit*: Initially I attempted this using the [sqlparse](https://pypi.org/project/sqlparse/) module without realizing it is intentionally non-validating. **This does not work.**

```
import sqlparse

# open the SQL file and read the contents
f_contents = open("example.sql").read()

# Use regexes to split the contents into individual SQL statements.
# This is unrelated to the issue
stmnt_list = split_statements(f_contents)

good_stmnts = []    # statements that executed correctly
for stmnt in stmnt_list:
    try:
        sqlparse.parse(stmnt)
        good_stmnts.append(stmnt)
    except sqlparse.exceptions.SQLParseError:
        print("Bad statement. Ignoring.\n'%s'" % stmnt)
```

I made a few unrelated (and optional) changes too:

- `good_stmnts` append inside the try block & rm `continue`
- caught only `SQLParseError`

Comment: sqlparse is parsing whatever I send. I'm getting no `SQLParseErrors` can you give me some examples?

Comment: @PhaniRithvij : You are absolutely right. The sqlparse module's docs even say "intentionally non-validating". The best way to make this work is to use a different module. I edited my answer but will need to return to fix it fully after finding the right module.

Comment: Sqlparse can split statement for ya